# Must input same numpy shape in numba's @vectorize?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, numba

- Window 10, Python=3.9, Numba=0.53.1, Numpy=1.22.2

I'm using numba with python for using my gpu.
This is my code sample.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize

@vectorize(["boolean(float64, int64, int64)"], target="cuda")
def vector_add_gpu(a, b, c):
    """
        Do something
    """
    return True

def main():
    a_source = np.ones(10, dtype=np.float64)
    b_source = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.int64)
    d_source = 10

    # Time the GPU function
    start = timer()
    vector_add_gpu(a_source, b_source, d_source)
    vector_add_gpu_time = timer() - start
    print("GPU function took %f seconds." % vector_add_gpu_time)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I got this error.

```
failed to broadcast argument #1
```

If I put same shape of arguments, it works.

Like

```
def main():
    a_source = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.float64)
    b_source = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.int64)
    d_source = 10
```

Sadly, I must use different shape of numpy arrays on my code.
So, can "vectorize" be used only if the shape of the numpy input is the same?

Comment: This is expected. What is the expected result? When the sizes are different, how Numba is supposed to find which item to match with which other? Does @guvectorize provide what you want ? See the documentation: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html . By the way, using a GPU is only fast if your problem is not memory bound and SIMD-friendly (this is especially true here due to data transfer).

Comment: I tried to clear "return True" and use @guvectorize like @guvectorize(["void(float64, int64, int64)"], '(), ()->()', target="cuda").
But I got this error: "arg #1: outer dimension mismatch"

Comment: And the result I expect is the conversion of the argument value of the numpy array put in the "vector_add_gpu" function.

Comment: `()` is for scalar so, yes, the array should have the same shape. I do not understand what you want to do in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for my lack of explanation.
I just want to run the function using numba with cuda. Because my code is slow...

Here is my code

```
#@vectorize(["boolean(int64, uint8, int64, int64, int64)"], target="cuda")
#@guvectorize(["void(int64, uint8, int64, int64, int64)"], '(), (), (), ()->()', target="cuda")
def _deleting_from_endpoints(coords, input_image, ar_x, ar_y, max_value):
    for (x, y) in coords:
        ar_x[0], ar_y[0] = x, y
        count = 0
        for i in range(1, max_value):
            count += 1
            x_, y_ = ar_x[i - 1], ar_y[i - 1]
            input_image[x_, y_] = 0
            if count > max_value:
                # input_image[ar_x[:count], ar_y[:count]] = 1
                for v in range(count):
                    input_image[ar_x[count], ar_y[count]] = 1
                break
            x__, y__ = np.where(input_image[x_ - 1:x_ + 2, y_ - 1:y_ + 2])
            if len(x__) != 0:
                ar_x[i] = x_ + x__[0] - 1
                ar_y[i] = y_ + y__[0] - 1
            else:
                break
    return True
```

---

**Arguments type**

```
coords: numpy array dtype=int64
input_image: numpy array dtype=uint8
ar_x: numpy array dtype=int64
ar_y: numpy array dtype=int64
max_value: int
```

Comment: Also input arguments have different shape.
So can I use numba with cuda in my code?

Comment: I'm not going to go ahead with that question, so I'm going to stop.